# Change filenames first letter

Tags: bash, perl

This a bit specific thing i need to do, and at this hour can't force my brain to think a fast way to do it, so this is my problem:

I got many files named, let's say:

```
word1_word2.ext
word3_word4.ext
word5_word5.ext
..
```

I need to make a bash/perl/etc script in osx to change their filenames, basically doing 3 things:

- Capitalize every word first letter
- Delete the _ chars
- Add the string '.full' after the name, before the extension

So, in other words..

'whatever_whatever2_whatever3.jpg' becames 'Whatever Whatever2 Whatever3.full.jpg'

Any help would be GREATLY welcomed :)

Comment: Are the underscores deleted or replaced with blanks? The text says deleted; the example says replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl one-line program will do as you ask

```
perl -e 'rename($_, tr/_/ /r =~ s/(?<!\.)\b([a-z])/\u$1/gr =~ s/(?=[^.]+$)/full./r) for glob "*.ext"'
```

It uses `tr///` to translate all underscores to spaces, and then `s///` to upper-case all lower-case letters that are preceded by a word boundary and not by a dot character, and again to precede the suffix with `full.`. It uses the non-destructive `/r` modifier for both `tr` and `s` so that they *return* the modified string instead of editing it in-place.

Comment: Worked Perfect! Used this instead of the first one only because it was shorter, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

A simple version that takes a list of files from the command line, renaming per your examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw(move);

for my $fn (@ARGV)
{
  my $newfn = $fn;

  # replace any spaces, tabs or _ with a single ' '  
  $newfn =~ s/[_ \t]+/ /g;     

  # uppercase the first letter of any words in the new string
  $newfn =~ s/(^|\s)([a-z])/$1\U$2/g;

  # and add '.full' before any extension
  $newfn =~ s/(\.[^\.]+)$/.full$1/g;

  # and rename
  move($fn, $newfn) or die "Unable to rename '$fn' to '$newfn': $!\n";
}
```

Comment: Why use `File::Copy::move` instead of the built-in `rename`? Also, why replace spaces with spaces? You are also capitalising the first letter of the file extension. Finally, you don't need the `/e` modifier if you use `\U$1` instead of `uc($1)`

Comment: That's right, my mistake -> replace underline with spaces, thanks

Comment: @Borodin Fixed the extension bug and removed `/e`, thanks. As for `File::Copy::move`, the last time I suggested using built-in `rename`, commenters jumped on me for *that* (`File::Copy::move` is more flexible, works across drives, etc. -- even though `rename` is perfectly suited for *this* task). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Perl-based `rename` command (often called `prename`), then:

```
$ prename -n 's/^./\U$&/; s/_(.)/\U$1/g ;s/\.[^.]+$/.full$&/' whatever_whatever2_whatever3.jpg 
whatever_whatever2_whatever3.jpg renamed as WhateverWhatever2Whatever3.full.jpg
$
```

The first substitute replaces the leading letter with upper-case; the second replaces `_x` with `X` throughout; the third inserts `.full` before the suffix string (a dot followed by non-dots).  If you want spaces instead of deleting the underscores, the fix is trivial (use `s/_(.)/ \U$1/g` as the second substitute).

Tested on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS derivative.